# "Program does not exist" when trying to use "ip" with Monit

Tags: bash, monit

I'm trying to restart openvpn in my namespace using monit.

The command that I use from the command line works fine:

```
 ip netns exec vpn openvpn --daemon --config /etc/openvpn/vpn.conf
```

But when I try and use it in monit it says:

> /etc/monit.d/monitrc:3: Program does not exist: 'ip'

How do I call the IP command or where is it found for the path?

Comment: You need to provide the full path to the ip utility in monitrc.

Comment: What is the full path to ip? WHereis found it for me usr/sbin/ip

Comment: Then it is `/usr/sbin/ip`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the full path to `ip`. To find the path, use `which ip`.

Sometimes the `type` command is a good alternative to `which` so you can try that too. `type` would tell you if `ip` was aliased to something else, for example.